# Not Redirecting To result_url After Password Change From Generated Ticket

Tags: auth0

I can successfully generate a [password change ticket via the Management API](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Tickets/post_password_change), but after the user changes their password, they are not redirected to the `result_url` specified when creating the ticket.

Steps Taken:

1. Obtain `client_credentials` access_token (server side)

```
POST https://MYTENANT.auth0.com/oauth/token
client_id=MYCLIENT&client_secret=MYSECRET&grant_type=client_credentials&audience=https%3A%2F%2FMYTENANT.auth0.com%2Fapi%2Fv2%2F
```

2. Generate password change ticket (server side)

```
POST https://MYTENANT.auth0.com/api/v2/tickets/password-change
Authorization: Bearer MYACCESSTOKEN
{
  "result_url": "https://MYDOMAIN/callback",
  "user_id": "auth0|MYUSERID"
}
```

3. Redirect user to `ticket` from previous response *(removed the "#" at the end of the ticket, but either way it doesn't seem to change anything)*

```
Status Code: 302
Location: https://MYTENANT.auth0.com/u/reset-password?ticket=MYTICKET
```

After successfully changing the password on the unaltered [Universal Login Password Reset page](https://auth0.com/docs/universal-login/password-reset), the user is just presented with a message saying:

[image: Password Updated Your password has been changed successfully. Use your new password to log in.]

How do you redirect a user to a page after a password reset using Auth0's Universal Login Password Reset page? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this is just an "early adopter" issue. I was using the "New Experience" *(which in their defense, does have the `BETA` badge)* and as soon as I switched back to the "Classic Experience" it worked as expected.

[image: The default look and feel for your Universal Login pages. Classic Vs New]

I'll leave this up in case anyone else runs into this in the future.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful! One question, if you use the result_url, is it possible to sign-in the user automatically, or does the user still need to sign in after changing the password?

Comment: I am using "New" and currently does **not** have 'beta' badge and it is not redirecting after successfully changing password.

Ideas?